# RxJava retryWhen bizarre behavior

Tags: java, rx-java, reactive-programming

I'm playing with the RxJava [retryWhen](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/retry.html) operator. Very little is found about it on the internet, the only one worthy of any mention being [this](http://blog.danlew.net/2016/01/25/rxjavas-repeatwhen-and-retrywhen-explained). That too falls short of exploring the various use cases that I'd like to understand. I also threw in asynchronous execution and retry with back-off to make it more realistic.

My setup is simple: I've a class `ChuckNorrisJokesRepository` that returns random number of Chuck Norris jokes from a JSON file. My class under test is `ChuckNorrisJokesService` which is shown below. The use cases I'm interested in are as follows:

1. Succeeds on 1st attempt (no retries)
2. Fails after 1 retry
3. Attempts to retry 3 times but succeeds on 2nd hence doesn't retry 3rd time
4. Succeeds on 3rd retry

**Note**: The project is available on my [GitHub](https://github.com/asarkar/java/blob/master/concurrency-learning/src/main/java/org/abhijitsarkar/rx/ChuckNorrisJokesService.java).

**ChuckNorrisJokesService.java**:

```
@Slf4j
@Builder
public class ChuckNorrisJokesService {
    @Getter
    private final AtomicReference<Jokes> jokes = new AtomicReference<>(new Jokes());

    private final Scheduler scheduler;
    private final ChuckNorrisJokesRepository jokesRepository;
    private final CountDownLatch latch;
    private final int numRetries;
    private final Map<String, List<String>> threads;

    public static class ChuckNorrisJokesServiceBuilder {
        public ChuckNorrisJokesService build() {
            if (scheduler == null) {
                scheduler = Schedulers.io();
            }

            if (jokesRepository == null) {
                jokesRepository = new ChuckNorrisJokesRepository();
            }

            if (threads == null) {
                threads = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
            }

            requireNonNull(latch, "CountDownLatch must not be null.");

            return new ChuckNorrisJokesService(scheduler, jokesRepository, latch, numRetries, threads);
        }
    }

    public void setRandomJokes(int numJokes) {
        mergeThreadNames("getRandomJokes");

        Observable.fromCallable(() -> {
            log.debug("fromCallable - before call. Latch: {}.", latch.getCount());
            mergeThreadNames("fromCallable");
            latch.countDown();

            List<Joke> randomJokes = jokesRepository.getRandomJokes(numJokes);
            log.debug("fromCallable - after call. Latch: {}.", latch.getCount());

            return randomJokes;
        }).retryWhen(errors ->
                errors.zipWith(Observable.range(1, numRetries), (n, i) -> i).flatMap(retryCount -> {
                    log.debug("retryWhen. retryCount: {}.", retryCount);
                    mergeThreadNames("retryWhen");

                    return Observable.timer(retryCount, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                }))
                .subscribeOn(scheduler)
                .subscribe(j -> {
                            log.debug("onNext. Latch: {}.", latch.getCount());
                            mergeThreadNames("onNext");

                            jokes.set(new Jokes("success", j));
                            latch.countDown();
                        },
                        ex -> {
                            log.error("onError. Latch: {}.", latch.getCount(), ex);
                            mergeThreadNames("onError");
                        },
                        () -> {
                            log.debug("onCompleted. Latch: {}.", latch.getCount());
                            mergeThreadNames("onCompleted");

                            latch.countDown();
                        }
                );
    }

    private void mergeThreadNames(String methodName) {
        threads.merge(methodName,
                new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(Thread.currentThread().getName())),
                (value, newValue) -> {
                    value.addAll(newValue);

                    return value;
                });
    }
}
```

For brevity, I'll only show the Spock test case for the 1st use case. See my [GitHub](https://github.com/asarkar/java/blob/master/concurrency-learning/src/test/groovy/org/abhijitsarkar/rx/ChuckNorrisJokesServiceSpec.groovy) for the other test cases.

```
def "succeeds on 1st attempt"() {
    setup:
    CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(2)
    Map<String, List<String>> threads = Mock(Map)
    ChuckNorrisJokesService service = ChuckNorrisJokesService.builder()
            .latch(latch)
            .threads(threads)
            .build()

    when:
    service.setRandomJokes(3)
    latch.await(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)

    Jokes jokes = service.jokes.get()

    then:
    jokes.status == 'success'
    jokes.count() == 3

    1 * threads.merge('getRandomJokes', *_)
    1 * threads.merge('fromCallable', *_)
    0 * threads.merge('retryWhen', *_)
    1 * threads.merge('onNext', *_)
    0 * threads.merge('onError', *_)
    1 * threads.merge('onCompleted', *_)
}
```

This fails with:

```
Too few invocations for:

1 * threads.merge('fromCallable', *_)   (0 invocations)
1 * threads.merge('onNext', *_)   (0 invocations)
```

What I'm expecting is that `fromCallable` is called once, it succeeds, `onNext` is called once, followed by `onCompleted`. What am I missing?

P.S.: Full disclosure - I've also posted this question on [RxJava GitHub](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/4207).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this after several hours of troubleshooting and with help from ReactiveX member David Karnok.

`retryWhen` is a complicated, perhaps even buggy, operator. The official doc and at least one answer here use `range` operator, which completes immediately if there are no retries to be made. See my [discussion](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/4207) with David Karnok.

The code is available on my [GitHub](https://github.com/asarkar/java/blob/master/concurrency-learning/src/main/java/org/abhijitsarkar/rx/ChuckNorrisJokesService.java) complete with the following test cases:

1. Succeeds on 1st attempt (no retries)
2. Fails after 1 retry
3. Attempts to retry 3 times but succeeds on 2nd hence doesn't retry 3rd time
4. Succeeds on 3rd retry

Comment: So what was the cause of that 'bizarre behavior'?

Comment: @YaroslavStavnichiy You can follow the link in my answer for details, but in short `range` completed immediately thus skipping `onNext` and going straight to `onCompleted`. As I said in my answer, I've since then rewritten the code to not use  `range`.

Comment: I asked because I did not see that in your answer, perhaps you should update it. And why exactly did the `range` complete immediately? Was that because `numRetries` was set to zero (you forgot to set it)?

Comment: @YaroslavStavnichiy It's in my answer alright "range operator, which will fail if there are no retries to be made". I've now rephrased that statement to make it clearer. As for the `numRetries=0`, it was intentional (use case #1 in my question). `numRetries=0` means "I don't want to retry, I'll take the result of the first call or fail.

Comment: @Abhijit Your github link is broken