# Exponential Backoff in RxJava

Tags: java, java-8, rx-java, exponential-backoff

I have an API that takes an `Observable` that triggers an event.

I want to return an `Observable` that emits a value every `defaultDelay` seconds if an Internet connection is detected, and delays `numberOfFailedAttempts^2` times if there's no connection.

I've tried a bunch of various styles, the biggest problem I'm having is `retryWhen's` observable is only evaluated once:

```
Observable
    .interval(defaultDelay,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .repeatWhen((observable) ->
         observable.concatMap(repeatObservable -> {
             if(internetConnectionDetector.isInternetConnected()){
                 consecutiveRetries = 0;
                 return observable;
             } else {
                 consecutiveRetries++;
                 int backoffDelay = (int)Math.pow(consecutiveRetries,2);
                 return observable.delay(backoffDelay, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                }
         }).onBackpressureDrop())
    .onBackpressureDrop();
```

Is there any way to do what I'm attempting to do? I found a related question (can't find it searching right now), but the approach taken didn't seem to work with a dynamic value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your code there are two mistakes:

1. In order to repeat some observable sequence, that sequence has to be finite. I.e. instead of `interval` you'd better use something like `just`, or `fromCallable` as I did in sample below.
2. From `repeatWhen`'s inner function you need to return new delayed observable source, so instead of `observable.delay()` you have to return `Observable.timer()`.

Working code:

```
public void testRepeat() throws InterruptedException {
    logger.info("test start");

    int DEFAULT_DELAY = 100; // ms
    int ADDITIONAL_DELAY = 100; // ms
    AtomicInteger generator = new AtomicInteger(0);
    AtomicBoolean connectionAlive = new AtomicBoolean(true); // initially alive

    Disposable subscription = Observable.fromCallable(generator::incrementAndGet)
            .repeatWhen(counts -> {
                AtomicInteger retryCounter = new AtomicInteger(0);
                return counts.flatMap(c -> {
                    int retry = 0;
                    if (connectionAlive.get()) {
                        retryCounter.set(0); // reset counter
                    } else {
                        retry = retryCounter.incrementAndGet();
                    }
                    int additionalDelay = ADDITIONAL_DELAY * (int) Math.pow(retry, 2);
                    logger.info("retry={}, additionalDelay={}ms", retry, additionalDelay);
                    return Observable.timer(DEFAULT_DELAY + additionalDelay, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
                });
            })
            .subscribe(v -> logger.info("got {}", v));

    Thread.sleep(220);
    logger.info("connection dropped");
    connectionAlive.set(false);
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    logger.info("connection is back alive");
    connectionAlive.set(true);
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    subscription.dispose();
    logger.info("test complete");
}
```

See detailed article about `repeatWhen` [here](http://blog.danlew.net/2016/01/25/rxjavas-repeatwhen-and-retrywhen-explained/).

Comment: The sample in the question was probably from the middle of my attempts since it seems to mix two approaches I used (one timer + retry based, one interval + delayed subscription based), the problem was actually from that article, which says that the input observable to retry/repeat should be used again. Does not using that observable cause issues with leaking subscriptions?

Comment: @AssortedTrailmix That was about the first level input, not about inner `flatMap`. See the last example in that article for very similar pattern.

Comment: ohh I see, sorry I missed that `counts` was what was getting flatMap'ed

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `retryWhen` operator to configure the delay when there's no connection. How to periodically emit items is a separate topic (look up `interval` or `timer` operators). Open a separate question if you can't figure it out.

I've an extensive example on my Github, but I'll give you the gist here.

```
RetryWithDelay retryWithDelay = RetryWithDelay.builder()
    .retryDelayStrategy(RetryDelayStrategy.RETRY_COUNT)
    .build()

Single.fromCallable(() -> {
    ...
}).retryWhen(retryWithDelay)
.subscribe(j -> {
    ...
})
```

`RetryWithDelay` is defined as follows. I used RxJava 2.x, so if you're using 1.x, the signature should be `Func1<Observable<? extends Throwable>, Observable<Object>>`.

```
public class RetryWithDelay implements
        Function<Flowable<? extends Throwable>, Publisher<Object>> {
    ...
}
```

[RetryWithDelay](https://github.com/asarkar/java/blob/master/concurrency-learning/src/main/java/org/abhijitsarkar/domain/RetryWithDelay.java) class.

[RetryStrategy](https://github.com/asarkar/java/blob/master/concurrency-learning/src/main/java/org/abhijitsarkar/domain/RetryDelayStrategy.java) enum.

This allows me to configure various sorts of timeouts, constant, linear, exponential, based on the `RetryDelayStrategy`. For your use case, you'd choose `CONSTANT_DELAY_TIMES_RETRY_COUNT` delay strategy and call `retryDelaySeconds(2)` when building `RetryWithDelay`.

`retryWhen` is a complicated, perhaps even buggy, operator. Most examples you'll find online use the `range` operator, which will fail if there are no retries to be made. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38429128/839733) for details.

Answer (score 2):

I've always found `retryWhen` to be somewhat low-level so for exponential backoff I use a a builder (like Abhijit) that is unit tested and available for RxJava 1.x at [rxjava-extras](http://github.com/davidmoten/rxjava-extras). I'd suggest using a capped version so that the exponential increase of delay won't go beyond a maximum value you define.

This is how you use it:

```
observable.retryWhen(
    RetryWhen.exponentialBackoff(
        delay, maxDelay, TimeUNIT.SECONDS)
    .build());
```

I disagree that `retryWhen` is buggy but if you find a bug report it to RxJava. Bugs  are fixed fast!

You'll need *rxjava-extras* 0.8.0.6 or later which is on Maven Central:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.davidmoten</groupId>
    <artifactId>rxjava-extras</artifactId>
    <version>0.8.0.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Let me know if you need the RxJava 2.x version. The same functionality is available in [rxjava2-extras](http://github.com/davidmoten/rxjava2-extras) from 0.1.4.

Comment: I knew I'd seen this somewhere! I don't want to reinvent the wheel here so I'm probably going to go with this and look at the implementation to see how I should have went about it

Comment: Today I noticed I forgot to implement the max back off, but it looks like that method signature doesn't exist for me when using version 0.8.0.6

Comment: I was in a hurry the other day so I told myself I'd come back to the piece of code I needed it for, it seems this solution doesn't have the behavior I expected, and that's the retry should reset after a successful invocation (which makes sense since that requires "out-of-band" communication). I think the repeatWhen approach outlined below is what I need in my current situation, this approach seems optimized for the more common situation of "retry until it works" vs "retry always, and delay longer if it doesn't work"

Comment: What about `repeat ().retryWhen()` to meet your retry always requirement?

Comment: That's what I went with based on the answer with the retryWhen observable  + flatMap. 

I think the two things I was missing were to flatMap on the retryWhen observable instead of just returning a new one, and to *not* return the source observable from inside flatMap (that caused a subtle memory leak and didn't work correctly)